# Correcting wide angle photos from iPhone 6 on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, software-recommendation, image-editing

I'm looking to correct lens distortion from my iPhone 6 when I take certain wide angle photos.

Take this picture of Pittsburgh taken on the Monongahela river just upstream of the point:

[image: monongahela]

If I try to rotate it in Photos - the [left side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLKKU.png) needs -5° rotation for vertical elements to look vertical. The [center of attention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJfjg.png) is vertical at 0 degrees rotation. The [far right side](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fZJm.png) needs +8° adjustment.

I'm looking for a way to use a high quality filter to adjust for the physical characteristics of the iPhone 6 lens as described in step three of this tutorial:

- [Where Lightroom on the PC/Mac has a database of common lenses and the corrections needed for perspective problems](http://www.digitalcameraworld.com/2014/04/03/lightroom-lens-correction-how-to-fix-common-lens-and-perspective-problems/)

I would like to:

- Avoid carrying a computer (or waiting to return to one) to edit photos like this.
- Avoid getting Lightroom if there is a more narrow lens distortion program that fits this need. (A small database of common lens perspective correction factors)
- Do the editing on iOS alone.

What software options exist for this task?

Comment: p.s. If the solution I want to avoid is one you like for this task, feel free to answer and explain how to automate it and/or if the iOS version of  Lightroom works to correct this without needing a Mac.

Comment: SKRWT by mjagielski https://appsto.re/cl/JcAUX.i ? Haven't tried it though.

Comment: Have you tried [Pixelmator](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pixelmator/id924695435?mt=8) software? It has been ported to iOS while ago.

Comment: @EirNym I love Pixelmator - I didn't think to check if it had that feature on iOS. I will report back. Thanks!

Comment: Pixelmatr has nothing on Mac or iOS to correct for this keystone/wide angle distortion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may wish to try [SKRWT](http://skrwt.com) for iOS.

From an [article from PhotoApps.Expert](https://photoapps.expert/tips/2015/2/17/skrwt-great-ios-app-squaring-perspective#.Vc9aJKOH1Z8):

> If you've ever shot a photo of a tall building from the ground, you know when 
>   you tilt up at it, the perspective goes wonky and your beautiful
>   square building starts to look like the pyramids of Egypt.
>
> SKRWT by mjagielski [$1.99 on the App Store] is an app that makes
>   correcting that perspective distortion extremely simple. Not only does
>   it do *keystone correction*, but it can also fix wide angle lens
>   distortion.

I tested it with a snapshot of Minneapolis. (I didn't spend a lot of time on this.  Just to test.)

[image: Before]
[image: After]

Comment: Looks promising. I was tempted to ask you to upload the originals so I could grab a copy and see how the quality is of the details, but the reviews and app web site look so good, I'm buying it now. I may owe you a beer in addition to the bounty. Surly, Indeed, Fulton or ??

Comment: LOL! Glad to help!  I did Minneapolis in your honor. ;)  I'm afraid I'll be heading East so I won't be in the Twin Cities again for the foreseeable future.  Enjoy my beer!

Comment: I'll hold the chit till we can meet. Sorry I missed your visit here.

Answer (score 0):

The SCRWE is still limited. Desktop Photoshop has the answer when applying Crop you can put a check mark on Perpective control and apply one side or all of them, really cool. I tried to find an iOS app to do that but not found any yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your first shot of Minneapolis is closer to reality than the distorted one you "corrected" in the app. Perspective is not the same thing as lens distortion. The top of the building is further away from your eye so it should appear smaller when flattened in 2D. The bottom photo can't exist in reality so I have no idea why everyone wants photos to have parallel lines. iPhone cameras do this distortion thing automatically with the camera software and I hate it.